# Validad y forzar a que se ejecute una consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un comando mysql que actualiza un campo restando su actual cantidad menos 1 numero en especifico:

```
$bd->query("update productos set stock = stock - 10 where id = 1");
```

ahora bien, ahy veces en que el sistema esta saturado o no se ejecuta esta accion por x motivos.
quisiera ver si existe alguna forma de validad que se ejecuto esta sentencia y si no es hacer volverlo a ejecutar hasta lograr que se ejecute.

Lo que yo intente es:
if($bd->query("update productos set stock = stock - 10 where id = 1")){.....

pero asi se ejecute o no igual me sale true esa condicional

Comment: Puedes usar [transacciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html). Saludos

Comment: Puedes usar transacciones como bien dice @MauricioContreras, aunque cabe señalar que las transacciones sólo funcionan en tablas InnoDB. También, puedes verificar si el número de filas afectadas es mayor que 1.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _"hay veces en que el sistema está saturado"_? Para llegar a ese punto se requiere de cierta cantidad de usuarios realizando peticiones al mismo tiempo o falta de optimización de conexiones y consultas. Un paso previo es analizar la cantidad de filas afectadas, si es cero, enviar un mensaje al usuario para que intente nuevamente.